# WSO2Apimanager Patch revert

Tags: wso2

I applied a patch into /repository/components/patches/ and it has been deployed in /repository/components/plugins/

Then i removed the patch and restarted the apimanager with sewso2server.bat -DapplyPatchesrver  but the particular jar is still exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the same jar, even though it has the same name. If you check md5sum of the jar you will understand. What happens here is that when you patch a jar, it replaces the original jar in plugins. When you revert a patch the original one replaces the patched one.

Comment: I applied a patch included a jar which is not existing before in plugins directory. But after revert the patch (after removing form patches) still the same jar exists in plugins. 
How to know whether patch is reverted or not ?

Comment: If you want to add a new jar you should put it to either `repository/components/lib` (if the jar is non-osgi) or `repository/components/dropins` (if the jar is osgi). You can patch only the jars available in `plugins` directory.